# How to get the selected checkbox value in post action in mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have got a checkbox list populated from database , I want to get the ID of each checkbox list during post action so that I can save that in the db , Below is the Code : 
Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ITrackdayRepository trackdayResp = new TrackdayRepository();
        IQueryable<Object> getAllEvents = trackdayResp.GetEventsSelectlist();
        var m = new SelectList(getAllEvents,"ID","Name");
        ViewData["events"] = new SelectList(getAllEvents.ToList(), "EventID","Date");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Admin/Voucher/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get all the selected checkboxlist, do db insertion

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View

```
<label>Events</label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <% foreach (var item in (SelectList)ViewData["events"]) { %>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="<%=item.Value %>" />
                  <label for="<%=item.Value%>"><%=item.Text%></label>
                  <br />

        <% } %>  
        </td>
```

I want to pass selected  <%=item.Value %> of the checkbox list to the post aqction of create , so that i can save it like 1,2,3,4 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple . Use FormCollection in your Parameter list of Action method in your controller and then create a String Array for your CheckBoxBox values in your model .

Now Assign formvalue["Your_CheckBoxBox_value"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

to your newly created String Array in your Controller ........

```
     public ActionResult Create()
{
    ITrackdayRepository trackdayResp = new TrackdayRepository();
    IQueryable<Object> getAllEvents = trackdayResp.GetEventsSelectlist();
    var m = new SelectList(getAllEvents,"ID","Name");
    ViewData["events"] = new SelectList(getAllEvents.ToList(), "EventID","Date");
    return View();
} 

//
// POST: /Admin/Voucher/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        // Get all the selected checkboxlist, do db insertion
        model.CheckBoxValues=collection["Your_CheckBox_valueOnView"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);




        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to pass only the selected checkboxes when you post the form then do the following [as suggested]:

```
var myAnswers = collection["name"];
```

and then iterate through it and save it or you can try this way to

[ASP.Net MVC List of Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731345/asp-net-mvc-list-of-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1):

all grouped checkboxes are returned as an array  i.e  1,4,8  you just request

```
var myAnswers = collection["name"];
// split myAnswers here if required
```

in your code  or am i missing something bigger here?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, use `FormCollection` in your Parameter list of Action method in your controller and then create a String Array for your `CheckBoxBox` values in your model.

Now Assign

```
formvalue["Your_CheckBoxBox_value"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

to your newly created String Array in your Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ITrackdayRepository trackdayResp = new TrackdayRepository();
    IQueryable<Object> getAllEvents = trackdayResp.GetEventsSelectlist();
    var m = new SelectList(getAllEvents,"ID","Name");
    ViewData["events"] = new SelectList(getAllEvents.ToList(), "EventID","Date");
    return View();
} 

// POST: /Admin/Voucher/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        // Get all the selected checkboxlist, do db insertion
        model.CheckBoxValues=collection["Your_CheckBox_valueOnView"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```